# Shadow mode testing in Python

Tags: python, testing

I have a legacy Batch Job executor written in Perl, now I am redesigning and rewriting this in Python.

I would want this migration to be smooth hence I was thinking to run Python-based executor in [shadow mode](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8001422B1/en) to Perl based executor.

Do we have any readymade framework in Python for this?

Note: Batch Job executor is a short-lived process that gets launched multiple times a day by a Job scheduler (based on a schedule) and is responsible for executing user commands specified in the Batch Job configuration. It has lots of features, for ex: it has a mechanism to send a notification to the configured set of people in case of command failure, users can configure checking for some dependency before executing the command, users can also specify configurations for rescheduling in case the command fails etc.